# Enabling SAML SSO: where is the "Use Single Sign-On" permission?

Tags: permissions, profile, single-sign-on, saml

We've set up Single Sign on with SAML. Our IdP is OneLogin and using their link, we are able to connect.

We now want to disable password login for some users in Salesforce.
[Salesforce's documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com) points me towards a "Use Single Sign On" or "Is Single Sign On Enabled" permission (depending on the age of the document) on the user profile, however I cannot find this permission. Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to say that this feature is now fully accessible to administrators. It has been possible to prevent users from using their Salesforce credentials when they were SSO-enabled but it required contacting Salesforce support.

As of Summer '20 ([release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_security.htm)), you can configure SSO in a way that it prevents users from using their internal credentials.

[image: Single Sign-On Settings]

Answer (score 8):

You will find the "Is Single Sign-On Enabled" checkbox on the User profile under the System Permissions group. Please note that this permission is related to delegated authentication and not to SAML SSO.

Comment: Is also worth noting that this field is a bit of a misnomer. It should actually read something like "Force Single Sign-On" but the way it reads makes it sound like an option.

Comment: Just curious, does this permission only show up in the User record after delegated authentication is enabled for the org?

Comment: Yes - it's not visible before delegated authentication is enabled by support.

Comment: I have an active SSO setup but don't see the "Is Single Sign On Enabled" box - has this been deprecated?

Comment: @jaw999 this ONLY appears after you disallow login via login.salesforce.com. So annoying :(

Comment: @zaitsman no that's not true. Disallowing login via lsc is unrelated.

Comment: @DavidBrossard that’s how it worked in my orgs (multiple). Until I turned it on that checkbox didn’t even show up for me.

Comment: That's odd. Did you change profile perms too?

Answer (score 1):

if Is Single Sign-On Enabled is not visible, then just open Single sign on settings and enable " Disable login with Salesforce credentials ". Then you can see Is Single Sign-On Enabled on profile.