# Implementing SAML SSO - Azure and federation id in Salesforce. Need to force sso but only for some users (not admins or integration users)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Implementing SAML SSO - Azure and federation id in Salesforce. Need to force sso but only for some users (not admins or integration users) Can't find how to only have it forced for some.

Found: [Enabling SAML SSO: where is the "Use Single Sign-On" permission?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35171/enabling-saml-sso-where-is-the-use-single-sign-on-permission)

but that doesn't really answer it. If we turn on the Disable login with Salesforce credentials
settings, then that would force it for everyone. At least that is my understanding.

The "Is Single Sign-On Enabled"  reads that it is only for delegated authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can SAML SSO be selectively enforced for a group of users?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366958/can-saml-sso-be-selectively-enforced-for-a-group-of-users)

Comment: Mostly. it doesn't mention that once you turn off the settings. and haven't changed it on the profile, the mydomain url won't work to use ID & PW. For our sandbox, we had to use test.salesforce.com for users without a fed id